# Celery gives connection reset by peer

Tags: python, celery

I setup the rabbitmqserver and added the users using the following steps:

```
uruddarraju@*******:/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.2.3$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_users 
Listing users ...
guest   [administrator]
phantom [administrator]
phantom1    []

sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p phantom phantom1 ".*" ".*" ".*"

uruddarraju@******:/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.2.3$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :5672
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      31341/beam.smp
```

My celery config is like:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://phantom:phantom1@10.98.85.92/phantom'
```

My code is like:

```
__author__ = 'uruddarraju'

from celery import Celery
import time
import celeryconfig

app = Celery('tasks')
app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    print 'sleeping'
    time.sleep(20)
    print 'awoke'
    return x + y
```

When I try to run

```
celery -A celery worker --loglevel=info
```

I get

```
[2014-07-08 23:30:05,028: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://phantom:**@10.98.85.92:5672/phantom:
[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
[2014-07-08 23:30:07,101: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://phantom:**@10.98.85.92:5672/phantom:
[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...
```

Everything looks just perfect !! Can someone help me what I am missing here ?

Comment: Do you have port 5672 open? Is the `/phantom` part of the connection url correct?

Comment: @Eric Workman Yes, to confirm I did a telnet: LM-SJN-00871893:tasks uruddarraju$ telnet 10.98.85.92 5672
Trying 10.98.85.92...
Connected to <hostname>.
Escape character is '^]'.
^] 

The /phantom is for the virtual host I created, I used this document here: [link] (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html)

Comment: Take a look at the rabbitmq log file, usually located at /var/log/rabbitmq/

Comment: =INFO REPORT==== 9-Jul-2014::12:00:00 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.401.0> (10.225.82.229:52828 -> 10.98.85.92:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 9-Jul-2014::12:00:00 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.401.0> (10.225.82.229:52828 -> 10.98.85.92:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 9-Jul-2014::12:00:12 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.405.0> (10.225.82.229:52832 -> 10.98.85.92:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 9-Jul-2014::12:00:12 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.405.0> (10.225.82.229:52832 -> 10.98.85.92:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

@user2027279 This is what I see in the time span

Comment: Any comments please ?

Comment: Did you happen to name that file celery.py? Your worker command `celery -A celery worker --loglevel=info` is trying to start a worker from a file called `celery.py`.

Comment: Yes I did, but that should not be a root cause to the connection reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved once I deployed my code to production, and upgrading the celery to 3.1.12. I inititally used 3.0.19 but later upgraded and did not find any issues. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 6):

I found the Connection rest by peer error, and assumed RabbitMQ was not listening on the port or there was a firewall blocking it. That was not the case.

Running RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, version installed by apt: 3.5.7-1ubuntu0.16.04.1

The output of 'netstat -a' for Rabbit's port 5672 looked like:

```
$ netstat -a|grep -i amqp
tcp6       0      0 [::]:amqp               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

However, Rabbit was in fact listening on both the IPv4 address and the IPv6 address. I verified this with netcat.

To reach Rabbit from another machine, you have to set up a user account with something like the following commands:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user celery celerypassword
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost celery_vhost
sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags celery celerytag
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p celery_vhost celery .* .* .*
```

The issue was my URL. Mine looked like:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://celery:celerypassword@10.0.3.3//'
```

After that penultimate forward slash is the name of the vhost. Above, I gave my vhost the name celery_vhost. To connect, I needed to change the URL to:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://celery:celerypassword@10.0.3.3/celery_vhost'
```

I discovered this looking at the Rabbit logs in /var/log/rabbitmq. There's a .log file that contained the following error when I had the wrong URL:

```
{handshake_error,opening,0,
{amqp_error,access_refused,
"access to vhost '/' refused for user 'celery'",
'connection.open'}}
```

Comment: If you want to check list of users and list of vhosts, you can use `rabbitmqctl list_users` and `rabbitmqctl list_vhosts`

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` error that stumped me for quite a while. After looking in the rabbit logs, I saw that it was logging that the creds were invalid. After changing them in rabbit admin, it started working again.